# XML Parsing. Trying to get attributes

Tags: java, xml

I'm developing a java class to parse this xml file:

```
<document src="xmls/sections/modules/200_1.xml">
<module name="product_info" id="1">
    <product_primary_id>200</product_primary_id>
    <product_section_id>1</product_section_id>
    <product_section_item_id></product_section_item_id>

    <type>1</type>
    <position>1</position>
    <align>top</align>

    <url href="productview/info.html"></url>
</module>
</document>
```

And I've this java class:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(contingut);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //loop a cada module
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("module");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        Element element = (Element) node;
        if(element.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Log.d("debugging","product_primary_id: "+getValue("product_primary_id",element));
            Log.d("debugging","product_section_id: "+getValue("product_section_id",element));
            //Log.d("debugging","product_section_item_id: "+getValue("product_section_item_id",element));
            Log.d("debugging","type: "+getValue("type",element));
            Log.d("debugging","position: "+getValue("position",element));
            Log.d("debugging","align: "+getValue("align",element));
            //Log.d("debugging","url: "+getValue("url",element));   
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see, it's looping for every "module" tag and getting its child value. But I need name attribute from module, but as It's a NodeList, can't use method `getAttribute("name");`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
Element element = (Element) node;
element.getAttribute("name")
```

to retrieve the `name` atttribute for the node that represents the `module` tag. You can do so because the `module` tag is an element itself, too. The `getAttribute()` method is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("module")
```

Returns a List of elements with the given tag name i.e. module, you have to use the **getAttribute** function inside of your for statement, when you are iterating over the list of nodes.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29